# How can I change the grid of numerical integration?

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm using numerical integration for calculating some integrals which depend on two parameters. In low range of parameters I get precise results without any further option but in high range of parameters, the results do not have enough precision where the functions are very very localized and tend to Dirac delta function. I guess that the problem relates to grid because it is needed to use a very compact grid for a very compact function. Now I want to know how can I compact the grid so that is suitable for my localized function? I have read the documentation for numerical integration and specially its methods and rules. For example I remember that `LocalAdaptive` or `CartessianRule` methods helped me to get more precise results in some other numerical integration but I'm not sure these methods can help me this time. Any idea?

*And finally a question:* Given the very localized functions, does decreasing the limits of integration (for example $\int_0^{10} \to \int_0^{1}$) decrease computation time or increase the precision of computation? I mean does Mathematica respond to decreasing the limits and adapts the grid to it (and so increase the precision) or simply use the same grid so speedup the computation ?

**Addendum 1**

One of my integral is

```
me = 1;
M = mp + me;
ω = 10000;
mp = 1836;
α = 0.8080295675491966`;
β = 4985.705218556087`;
γ = SetPrecision[0.5*M*ω, 50];
{α, β} = SetPrecision[{α, β}, 50];
norm = (16*π^2*(Sqrt[π/2] (-2 α Sqrt[β] + 
          E^(α^2/(2 β)) Sqrt[
            2 π] (α^2 + β) Erfc[α/(Sqrt[
                2] Sqrt[β])]))/(128 β^(5/2) γ^(3/
           2)))^(-1/2);
norm = SetPrecision[norm, 50];

(* first numerical integration *)
intrE[r_, 
   re_] := (E^(-2 r (α + 
          r β)) (E^(-((2 (me re + mp (-r + re))^2 γ)/
            M^2)) - 
       E^(-((2 (me re + mp (r + re))^2 γ)/
            M^2))) M^2)/(4 mp (me + mp) γ);

de[re_?NumericQ] := (2*π)/re norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrE[r, re], {r, 0, 0.1}];

intrp[r_, 
   rp_] := (E^(-2 r (α + 
          r β)) (E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (-r + rp))^2 γ)/
            M^2)) - 
       E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (r + rp))^2 γ)/
            M^2))) M^2)/(4 me (me + mp) γ);
dp[rp_?NumericQ] := (2*π)/rp norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrp[r, rp], {r, 0, 0.1}];

(*second numerical integration and final result *)
COLr = -8*π^2*
  NIntegrate[
   dE[re]*dP[rp] re rp, {r, 0, 0.1}, {re, 0, 0.1}, {rp, Abs[re - r], 
    r + re}]
```

**Addendum 2**

I don't know the exact value of  `COLr`, however I'm sure that the sum of `COLr` and `CORr` must be equal to `TPr` namely `COLr+CORr=TPr` I just know the exact value of `TPr` is `-113.11876522958521` as you can simply reproduce it. I have introduced them in the following:

```
\[CapitalGamma]r[re_, rp_, r_] := 
  norm^2*Exp[-2 \[Alpha] r - 
     2 \[Beta] r^2 - (2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2 (me^2 re^2 + mp^2 rp^2 + me mp (-r^2 + re^2 + rp^2))];

\[CapitalGamma]Cr[re_, rp_, r_] := \[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] - 
   de[re]*dp[rp];

TPr = -8*\[Pi]^2*
   NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] re rp, {r, 0, 0.05}, {re, 0,
      0.05}, {rp, Abs[re - r], r + re}, Method -> "CartesianRule"];
CORr = -8*\[Pi]^2*
   NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]Cr[re, rp, r] re rp, {r, 0, 0.1}, {re, 0,
      0.1}, {rp, Abs[re - r], r + re}];
```

Comment: Please include a minimal working example with your post.

Comment: @Syed I added one of my integrals, however its computation takes long

Comment: Is `Colr` in your example about -2.0835*10^-47?

Comment: @AlexTrounev NO!! it should be greater than 10 (in absolute sense)

Comment: @Wisdom Is region of integration for `TPr` is different then for `CORr` and `COLr`?

Comment: No, in fact the limits of all of them are $0\to\infty$ however I know that they are so localized for these values of parameters so I changed the limits to a small value. For `TPr` I set the limits to `0.05` and because of its fast computation I found that this limit is good enough to capture the correct value, but about `CORr` and `COLr` I was not sure that `0.05` is good enough, on the other hand their computation took so long so I set `0.1` for more reliability

Comment: @Wisdom What about limits for `rp` - is it `{rp, Abs[re - r], r + re}` or `{rp, 0, Infinity}`?

Comment: No it's not $0 \to \infty$, the current limit is true. In fact its limits are determined by two other variables $r$ and $re$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be rationalization of expressions with using `Integrate`, `ImplicitRegion` and `NIntegrate` over region with option `AccuracyGoal` as follows

```
me = 1; mp = 1836;
M = mp + me;
\[Omega] = 10000;
\[Alpha] = Rationalize[0.8080295675491966, 10^-16];
\[Beta] = Rationalize[4985.705218556087, 10^-16];
\[Gamma] = M*\[Omega]/2;
norm = (16*\[Pi]^2*(Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (-2 \[Alpha] Sqrt[\[Beta]] + 
          E^(\[Alpha]^2/(2 \[Beta])) Sqrt[
            2 \[Pi]] (\[Alpha]^2 + \[Beta]) Erfc[\[Alpha]/(Sqrt[
                2] Sqrt[\[Beta]])]))/(128 \[Beta]^(5/2) \[Gamma]^(3/
           2)))^(-1/2);


(*first integration*)
intrE[r_, 
   re_] := (E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + 
          r \[Beta])) (E^(-((2 (me re + mp (-r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/
            M^2)) - 
       E^(-((2 (me re + mp (r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/
            M^2))) M^2)/(4 mp (me + mp) \[Gamma]);
iE = Integrate[r intrE[r, x], {r, 0, 1/10}, Assumptions -> x > 0];
de[re_?NumericQ] := 2 pi norm^2/re iE /. x -> re;

intrp[r_, 
  rp_] := (E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + 
         r \[Beta])) (E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (-r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/
           M^2)) - 
      E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/
           M^2))) M^2)/(4 me (me + mp) \[Gamma]); iP = 
 Integrate[r intrp[r, x], {r, 0, 1/10}, Assumptions -> x > 0];
dp[rp_?NumericQ] := 2 Pi norm^2/rp iP /. x -> rp;
```

We can analyze functions `de,dp` and get local maximum using

```
FindMaximum[re de[re],{re,1/200},WorkingPrecision\[Rule]30]
(*{773.69081636406771025946995102338658579598`30.,{re\[Rule]0.\
0070389080610579945439299803025480156721079922769234531152`30.}}*)
FindMaximum[rp dp[rp],{rp,1/10000},WorkingPrecision\[Rule]60]
(*1.4141208256290053754647409347022996687655573818723963994434606784224\
4490542412383413`60.*^6,{rp\[Rule]0.\
0001650244215391767777262999804333971330966709705474246520511124970815\
8738697`60.}}*)
```

With maximal `re, rp` we can defined regions of integration

```
    rpm = 0.00016502442153917677772629998; rem = \
0.00703890806105799454392998030; reg0 = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  0 <= r <= 100 rem && 0 <= re <= 100 rem && 
   Abs[re - r] <= rp <= r + re, {r, re, rp}]; 
region[0] = 
 RegionIntersection[reg0, 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= r <= 100 rem && 0 <= re <= 100 rem && 0 <= rp <= rpm, {r, re, 
    rp}]]; reg12 = region[0]; Do[
 region[i] = 
  RegionIntersection[reg0, 
   ImplicitRegion[
    0 <= r <= 100 rem && 0 <= re <= 100 rem && 
     i rpm <= rp <= (i + 1) rpm, {r, re, rp}]]; 
 reg12 = RegionUnion[reg12, region[i]];, {i, 3}]; region3 = 
 RegionDifference[reg0, reg12];
```

Numerical integration takes about 1 sec on CORE i7 9th Gen

```
 \[CapitalGamma]r[re_, rp_, r_] := 
  norm^2*Exp[-2 \[Alpha] r - 
     2 \[Beta] r^2 - (2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2 (me^2 re^2 + mp^2 rp^2 + me mp (-r^2 + re^2 + rp^2))];

\[CapitalGamma]Cr[re_, rp_, r_] := \[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] - 
   de[re]*dp[rp];

 -8*\[Pi]^2*(Sum[
     NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] re rp, 
      Element[{r, re, rp}, region[i]], AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 2], {i, 0, 3}] + 
    NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] re rp, 
     Element[{r, re, rp}, region3], AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 2]) // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {0.964911, -113.106}



-8*\[Pi]^2*(Sum[
     NIntegrate[de[re]*dp[rp] re rp, Element[{r, re, rp}, region[i]], 
      AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2], {i, 0, 3}] + 
    NIntegrate[de[re]*dp[rp] re rp, Element[{r, re, rp}, region3], 
     AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2]) // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {1.94581, -113.105}
```

The exact value is about -113.11875862400078. Therefore we have answer with error of $10^{-4}$ due to options `AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2`.

To make a balance `COLr+CORr=TPr` with absolute error of 10^-6 we use the code

```
me = 1; mp = 1836;
M = mp + me;
\[Omega] = 10000;
\[Alpha] = Rationalize[0.8080295675491966, 10^-50];
\[Beta] = Rationalize[4985.705218556087, 10^-50];
\[Gamma] = M*\[Omega]/2;
norm = (16*\[Pi]^2*(Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (-2 \[Alpha] Sqrt[\[Beta]] + 
          E^(\[Alpha]^2/(2 \[Beta])) Sqrt[
            2 \[Pi]] (\[Alpha]^2 + \[Beta]) Erfc[\[Alpha]/(Sqrt[
                2] Sqrt[\[Beta]])]))/(128 \[Beta]^(5/2) \[Gamma]^(3/
           2)))^(-1/2);
\[CapitalGamma]r[re_, rp_, r_] := 
  norm^2*Exp[-2 \[Alpha] r - 
     2 \[Beta] r^2 - (2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2 (me^2 re^2 + mp^2 rp^2 + me mp (-r^2 + re^2 + rp^2))];

\[CapitalGamma]Cr[re_, rp_, r_] := \[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] - 
   de[re]*dp[rp];

(*first numerical integration*)
intrE[r_, 
   re_] := (E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + 
          r \[Beta])) (E^(-((2 (me re + mp (-r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/
            M^2)) - 
       E^(-((2 (me re + mp (r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/
            M^2))) M^2)/(4 mp (me + mp) \[Gamma]);
iE = Integrate[r intrE[r, x], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {x > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, 
     M > 0, me > 0, mp > 0}];
de[re_?NumericQ] := 2 Pi norm^2/re iE /. x -> re;

intrp[r_, 
  rp_] := (E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + 
         r \[Beta])) (E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (-r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/
           M^2)) - 
      E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/
           M^2))) M^2)/(4 me (me + mp) \[Gamma]); iP = 
 Integrate[r intrp[r, y], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {y > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, 
    M > 0, me > 0, mp > 0}];
dp[rp_?NumericQ] := 2 Pi norm^2/rp iP /. y -> rp;

(*FindMaximum[re de[re],{re,1/200},WorkingPrecision\[Rule]30]
{773.69081636406771025946995102338658579598`30.,{re\[Rule]0.\
0070389080610579945439299803025480156721079922769234531152`30.}}
FindMaximum[rp dp[rp],{rp,1/10000},WorkingPrecision\[Rule]60]
{1.4141208256290053754647409347022996687655573818723963994434606784224\
4490542412383413`60.*^6,{rp\[Rule]0.\
0001650244215391767777262999804333971330966709705474246520511124970815\
8738697`60.}}*) 



rpm = 0.00016502442153917677772629998; rem = 0.00703890806105799454392998030; reg0 = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  0 <= r <= 100 rem && 0 <= re <= 100 rem && 
   Abs[re - r] <= rp <= r + re, {r, re, rp}]; 
region[0] = 
 RegionIntersection[reg0, 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= r <= 6 rem && 0 <= re <= 12 rem && 0 <= rp <= rpm, {r, re, 
    rp}]]; reg12 = region[0]; Do[
 region[i] = 
  RegionIntersection[reg0, 
   ImplicitRegion[
    0 <= r <= 6 rem && 0 <= re <= 12 rem && 
     i rpm <= rp <= (i + 1) rpm, {r, re, rp}]]; 
 reg12 = RegionUnion[reg12, region[i]];, {i, 5}]; region3 = 
 RegionDifference[reg0, reg12];


int1= With[{p = 
   8}, -8*\[Pi]^2*(Sum[
      NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] re rp, 
       Element[{r, re, rp}, region[i]], AccuracyGoal -> p, 
       PrecisionGoal -> p], {i, 0, 5}] + 
     NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] re rp, 
      Element[{r, re, rp}, region3], AccuracyGoal -> p - 2, 
      PrecisionGoal -> p - 2]) // AbsoluteTiming]

(*{3.1662883`, -113.11874897872505`}*)


int2= With[{p = 
   8}, -8*\[Pi]^2*(Sum[
      NIntegrate[de[re]*dp[rp] re rp, Element[{r, re, rp}, region[i]],
        AccuracyGoal -> p, PrecisionGoal -> p], {i, 0, 5}] + 
     NIntegrate[de[re]*dp[rp] re rp, Element[{r, re, rp}, region3], 
      AccuracyGoal -> p - 2, PrecisionGoal -> p - 2]) // 
  AbsoluteTiming]

(*Out[]= {131.119, -113.11803040119649`}*)

int3= With[{p = 
   8}, -8*\[Pi]^2*(Sum[
      NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]Cr[re, rp, r] re rp, 
       Element[{r, re, rp}, region[i]], AccuracyGoal -> p, 
       PrecisionGoal -> p], {i, 0, 5}] + 
     NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] re rp, 
      Element[{r, re, rp}, region3], AccuracyGoal -> p - 2, 
      PrecisionGoal -> p - 2]) // AbsoluteTiming]

(*Out[]= {3.34852, -0.00071959}*)
```

The balance `int2[[2]]+int3[[2]]-int1[[2]]`is about -1.01247*10^-6. To decrease error we can increase number of subregions `regions[i]`. For example,  to make a balance `COLr+CORr=TPr` with absolute error of 10^-7 we use 9 subregions and `ParallelTable` to decrease computation time as follows

```
me = 1; mp = 1836;
M = mp + me;
\[Omega] = 10000;
\[Alpha] = Rationalize[0.8080295675491966, 10^-50];
\[Beta] = Rationalize[4985.705218556087, 10^-50];
\[Gamma] = M*\[Omega]/2;
norm = (16*\[Pi]^2*(Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (-2 \[Alpha] Sqrt[\[Beta]] + 
          E^(\[Alpha]^2/(2 \[Beta])) Sqrt[
            2 \[Pi]] (\[Alpha]^2 + \[Beta]) Erfc[\[Alpha]/(Sqrt[
                2] Sqrt[\[Beta]])]))/(128 \[Beta]^(5/2) \[Gamma]^(3/
           2)))^(-1/2);
\[CapitalGamma]r[re_, rp_, r_] := 
  norm^2*Exp[-2 \[Alpha] r - 
     2 \[Beta] r^2 - (2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2 (me^2 re^2 + mp^2 rp^2 + me mp (-r^2 + re^2 + rp^2))];

\[CapitalGamma]Cr[re_, rp_, r_] := \[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] - 
   de[re]*dp[rp];

(*first numerical integration*)
intrE[r_, 
   re_] := (E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + 
          r \[Beta])) (E^(-((2 (me re + mp (-r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/
            M^2)) - 
       E^(-((2 (me re + mp (r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/
            M^2))) M^2)/(4 mp (me + mp) \[Gamma]);
iE = Integrate[r intrE[r, x], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {x > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, 
     M > 0, me > 0, mp > 0}];
de[re_?NumericQ] := 2 Pi norm^2/re iE /. x -> re;

intrp[r_, 
  rp_] := (E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + 
         r \[Beta])) (E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (-r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/
           M^2)) - 
      E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/
           M^2))) M^2)/(4 me (me + mp) \[Gamma]); iP = 
 Integrate[r intrp[r, y], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {y > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, 
    M > 0, me > 0, mp > 0}];
dp[rp_?NumericQ] := 2 Pi norm^2/rp iP /. y -> rp;

(*FindMaximum[re de[re],{re,1/200},WorkingPrecision\[Rule]30]
{773.69081636406771025946995102338658579598`30.,{re\[Rule]0.\
0070389080610579945439299803025480156721079922769234531152`30.}}
FindMaximum[rp dp[rp],{rp,1/10000},WorkingPrecision\[Rule]60]
{1.4141208256290053754647409347022996687655573818723963994434606784224\
4490542412383413`60.*^6,{rp\[Rule]0.\
0001650244215391767777262999804333971330966709705474246520511124970815\
8738697`60.}}*)

nn = 7; rpm = 0.00016502442153917677772629998; rem = \
0.00703890806105799454392998030; reg0 = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  0 <= r <= 100 rem && 0 <= re <= 100 rem && 
   Abs[re - r] <= rp <= r + re, {r, re, rp}]; 
region[0] = 
 RegionIntersection[reg0, 
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= r <= 6 rem && 0 <= re <= 12 rem && 0 <= rp <= rpm, {r, re, 
    rp}]]; reg12 = region[0]; Do[
 region[i] = 
  RegionIntersection[reg0, 
   ImplicitRegion[
    0 <= r <= 6 rem && 0 <= re <= 12 rem && 
     i rpm <= rp <= (i + 1) rpm, {r, re, rp}]]; 
 reg12 = RegionUnion[reg12, region[i]];, {i, nn}]; region3 = 
 RegionDifference[reg0, reg12];


reg = Join[Table[region[i], {i, 0, nn}], {region3}]; pr = 
 With[{p = 8}, Join[Table[p, {nn + 1}], {p - 2}]];



tab1 = -8*\[Pi]^2*
   ParallelTable[
    NIntegrate[de[re]*dp[rp] re rp, Element[{r, re, rp}, reg[[i]]], 
     AccuracyGoal -> pr[[i]], PrecisionGoal -> pr[[i]]], {i, 
     Length[pr]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {92.9688, {-22.487, -61.0637, -26.2565, -3.18275, -0.126354, \
-0.00173423, -8.40441*10^-6, -1.42971*10^-8, -5.31554*10^-13}}*)

tab2 = -8*\[Pi]^2*
   ParallelTable[
    NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]Cr[re, rp, r] re rp, 
     Element[{r, re, rp}, reg[[i]]], AccuracyGoal -> pr[[i]], 
     PrecisionGoal -> pr[[i]]], {i, Length[pr]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {1.44566, {-0.0000776321, -0.000337191, -0.000250858, \
-0.0000499317, -3.02574*10^-6, -4.88653*10^-8, -2.90574*10^-10, \
-6.00111*10^-13, -1.89854*10^-16}}*)



tab3 = -8*\[Pi]^2*
   ParallelTable[
    NIntegrate[\[CapitalGamma]r[re, rp, r] re rp, 
     Element[{r, re, rp}, reg[[i]]], AccuracyGoal -> pr[[i]], 
     PrecisionGoal -> pr[[i]]], {i, Length[pr]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*Out[]= {1.56184, {-22.4871, -61.064, -26.2567, -3.1828, -0.126357, \
-0.00173429, -8.40479*10^-6, -1.42977*10^-8, -5.31744*10^-13}}*)



eq = {Total[tab1[[2]]], Total[tab2[[2]]], -Total[tab3[[2]]]}

(*Out[]= {-113.118, -0.000718688, 113.119}*)

Total[eq]

Out[]= -1.09945*10^-7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. your method was so interesting for me, its speedup was amazing! however I didn't understand it completely for example why you added $2\pi ^2$ in the final expression. I would be appreciated if you add some explanations to your answer. Finally I can't verify your result (however seems wrong), Please see the addendum 2 in my question and apply it to your answer to see if your wonderful method gives the correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Wisdom See Update 1 to my answer. It looks like `TPr=COLr` , and `CORr` is about 0.

Comment: Thanks but as I said in addendum 2, the correct result for `TPr` is `-113,...` which is not equal to your result, however I know that the `CORr` posses a very small fraction of `TPr` and the most belongs to `COLr`, so it seems the general philosophy of your method is true, but its precision is not enough to capture the correct values.

Comment: @Wisdom Yes, you are right, integral `TPr` could be computed exactly as a function of 6 parameters and its value is about -113.11875862400078.

Comment: Thanks, so your method fails? no alternative to speedup computations?

Comment: @Wisdom Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks but it seems you didn't read my addendum 2 carefully, we need to `COLr+CORr=TPr`  while you just calculate `TPr` and `COLr`. On the other hand the order of magnitude of `CORr` is exactly $10^{-4}$ so we can't lost the precision at all!

Comment: @Wisdom See update 2 to my answer with error of about $10^{-6}$ for balance equation `COLr+CORr-TPr`

Comment: Dear @AlexTrounev Thanks you so much, I'm so excited for testing your method but when I run all of your codes, I get this `{1.6976886, -8 \[Pi]^2 (NIntegrate[
     de[re] dp[rp] re rp, {r, re, rp} \[Element] region3, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 8 - 2, PrecisionGoal -> 8 - 2] + 
    6 NIntegrate[
      de[re] dp[rp] re rp, {r, re, rp} \[Element] region[i], 
      AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8])}` namely it cannot calculate two last integrals. what's wrong about that?

Comment: @Wisdom Did you perform (*first integration*) code before?

Comment: Dear @AlexTrounev I tried your final code and it worked. It's very amazing. I have run these calculation on a cluster and after passing 4 days it returns just two first results and I'm sure the third result will take too longer! so this method is very very efficient and saves my time a lot. However there is a doubt for me: we don't calculate `int3` in this final code and obtain it just by balance equation, but how can we be sure its real value is the same? because the equation balance is something that should be satisfied in principle but we intend to verify it for our system

Comment: @Wisdom Actually we calculate `int3` in the last code. Also we can check convergence of this method by increasing number of subregions, for example, with  `{i, 0, 6}`, and  `{i, 0, 7}`. I can recommend  `ParallelTable` instead of `Sum` to decrease computation time for a large number of subregions.

Comment: Dear @AlexTrounev can you give me a contact way such as telegram id or email to ask some questions? this method is really amazing and can saves my time but I can't apply it to other cases if I don't understand its procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Wisdom Please, have a look at last update to my answer with error of $10^{-7}$ for balance equation. This code could be used with any `nn` to decrease error. Pay attention that contribution to `CORr` over last subregion (`region3`) is about $10^{-16}$.